# Window not opening

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I really have two questions; one is much broader than the other.
First, at the top of my code, I've used #define for naming my window class.
On MSDN they recommend using "const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]" down in the main function, but I couldn't get that to work. Does this have something to do with Unicode (I've had problems with the lpsz stuff as well which seems to be related to that perhaps)? Anyway, point being, I can't figure out why that didn't work.　It gave an error saying "Cannot assign const wchar_t to LPCSTR."

My second, and more broad question is, even in the state the code is in below, I debug with no errors and run, but no window opens. I cannot figure out what's missing. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define CLASS_NAME TEXT("Window Class")

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    //Registering the window class.//

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    if (!S_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Create Window//

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "CLASS_NAME", NULL, NULL, 100, 100, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Show Window//

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);


    //Message loop//

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: The problem you describe first is because MSDN's recommendations depend on your compiler being configured to build your program in Unicode mode, but you have it configured to build your program in multibyte mode.  We can't advise you how to correct that because you haven't told us what compiler you are using.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Comment: `S_OK` is defined as 0, so `!S_OK` evaluates to `true`, and you never create a window. This is not how you implement error handling, and I'm sure your compiler warned you about this.

Comment: @IInspectable, no, VS2010 at least passes over his code as posted without complaint.  I guess warning about dead code would produce too much noise.

Comment: What you do need to do though is learn to use the debugger correctly.  If you'd stepped through the program it would have been obvious what line of code was causing the problem.  You can start the program in single-step mode by using "Step Over" (F10) instead of "Start Debugging" (F5) or you can set a breakpoint with "Toggle Breakpoint" (F9) and the program will stop when it reaches that point in the code.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Actually I was thinking of [C4127](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h.aspx) ("conditional expression is constant").

Comment: @IInspectable, oh, right, I get that one with the OPs code if I turn warnings up to /W4 instead of the default /W3.

Comment: Thanks guys. I actually got this "working" in that the window is displayed, but I now have other problems with it. I'm gonna look more into the error handling, and definitely using the single-step method @Harry Johnston suggests.

Answer (score 3):

The code in question terminates right after registering a window class. It never even creates a window. The issue is the following attempt at error handling:

```
    if (!S_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

`S_OK` is a COM [HRESULT value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137.aspx), that evaluates to the constant value `0`. Consequently, `!S_OK` evaluates to `true`, so that branch is always taken, exiting the user-provided entry point. The compiler issues warning [C4127](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h.aspx) ("conditional expression is constant") at [warning level 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx) (which you should be using if at all possible).

Your first question is about mismatching character types (and encodings). The rules are documented under [working with strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407.aspx).